# Apache webserver's ServerName and/or ServerAlias should be registered on LAN's DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, web-server

If I create an Apache webserver into my LAN, with 2 VirtualHosts, both on port 80, should I register their ServerName and/or ServerAlias on my LAN's DNS server?

That's what I did (using in this example the values below):

LAN Domain Name = `company.local`
Domain Controllers' (and DNS Servers') System = Windows Server 2016
Webserver's hostname = `myserver`
Webserver's IP = `192.168.0.123`
Webserver's System = Ubuntu Server 22.04

Used `tracert 192.168.0.123` on my Windows Desktop (separated machine on same LAN), it answers `Tracing route to myserver.company.local [192.168.0.123]...`

Installed Apache on `myserver`. Just after installing, when using on my Desktop's browser `http://192.168.0.123` or `http://myserver.company.local`, it opens the "**Apache2 Default Page (It works!)**").

Then I configured Virtual Hosts on `myserver` using:

(Content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site_1.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@site_1
        ServerName site_1
        ServerAlias www.site_1
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site_1/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

(Content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site_2.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@site_2
        ServerName site_2
        ServerAlias www.site_2
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site_2/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

When I typed on my Desktop's browser any of these addresses:

```
http://site_1
http://site_2
http://www.site_1
http://www.site_2
http://site_1.company.local
http://site_2.company.local
http://www.site_1.company.local
http://www.site_2.company.local
```

It returns a page with the message
**Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.**.

When I typed on my Desktop's browser any of these addresses:

```
http://myserver.company.local
http://192.168.0.123
```

It returns the page of Virtual Host **site_1**, with the message
**Success! The site_1 virtual host is working!**.

Does it mean that I have to register the names `site_1` and `site_2` pointing to `192.168.0.123` on my LAN's DNS server?
Should I also register `www.site_1` and `www.site_2` pointing to `192.168.0.123`?
Or I have to register them as `site_1.myserver.company.local` and `site_2.myserver.company.local`?
Do I have to delete the register associating `myserver.company.local` with `192.168.0.123`?

Comment: each subdomain needs a target. how should the dns else know what it should answer? ;)

Comment: It worked using ServerNames `site1.company.local` and `site2.company.local` and registering on DNS server `site1.company.local` and `site2.company.local` pointing both to `192.168.0.123`, **BUT ONLY** after removing (from this DNS server) the registry `myserver.company.local` pointing to `192.168.0.123` (and even so, didn't work in SOME Ubuntu desktops using the same DNS server - in others Ubuntu desktops it did -, and in all Windows desktops I tested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DNS

**Domain Name System** is only translating domain from human-readable address to IP address.

In your case, any local domains in your LAN network should point to your **web SERVER** IP. *(not VMs)*

### Reverse Proxy

**Apache** or **Nginx**, what they do is listening on IP:port and read header of HTTP requests, they filter what user want (there exist [HOST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header). It maps what user want with local container/vm/service via socket or IP:PORT.

*Of course that tools are much more powerful, but it's out of the scope of this answer.*

---

There are a lot solutions for (local?) DNS, i'm not a fan of Microsoft and never used Windows Server. I'd like to configure my own dedicated DNS proxy instead (it caches responses from public DNS and let you configure itself as you wish). **Your solution is to point all DNS records to your reverse proxy server**:

```
myserver.company.local -> 192.168.0.123
site1.myserver.company.local -> 192.168.0.123
site2.myserver.company.local -> 192.168.0.123
```

of course you can do

```
myserver.company.local -> 192.168.0.123
site1.company.local -> 192.168.0.123
site2.company.local -> 192.168.0.123
```

There is only one magic, **Your SERVERNAME in config file must match DNS domain name.** - [apache example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html), [nginx example](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) - that's all.

Comment: Yes, it is a local DNS server for our LAN. I thought that, if there was in the DNS server the registry `myserver.company.local` pointing to `192.168.0.123`, and I configured the virtual hosts with the ServerNames `site1` and `site2`, when trying to reach `http://site2.myserver.company.local` (or `http://site2.myserver.company.local`), Apache could redirect to the configured directory (inside the machine `myserver.company.local`).